# Grouping the data having two different dates and take the latest date

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:1

```
Date     Customer  Amount
12-Dec   ABC       200
15-Dec    ABC       300
```

Output: 
I need to group the data by Customer and need to take the latest date for that unique record.

```
Date      Customer   Amount
15-Dec    ABC        500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to want aggregation :

```
select max(to_date(date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')), cust, sum(amount)
from table t
group by cust;
```

Comment: The output is not Proper. Grouping is not happening because of the date.

Comment: DD-MMM-YYYY is the type of Date.

Comment: @SubramanianKarunamoorthi. . . Then this should work as you want. You can explicit do type conversation.